# Unpublished app accessible from Play Store download link

Tags: android, download, google-play-console, android-app-links

I had uploaded an app to the google play store but after some time I lost its upload-keystore keys. So I unpublish the previous app and re-uploaded the new app.

What I am facing is the previous app is not visible in the search result, but it's accessible from the app download link.

Comment: You are saying that, you unpublished app from google play store. But it's accessible using download link which is unexpected?

Comment: @MdFarzan yes, it should not be accessible using the link.

Comment: Users who have already downloaded an app can do so forever, even if it is unpublished. This is intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alexander Hoffmann said, This app will be accessible to those who already downloaded the app. If any new user will try to access the app will be get an error like "*Something went wrong!*"